# AngularJs ReferenceError: $http is not defined

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework, angular-http

I have the following Angular function:

```
$scope.updateStatus = function(user) {    
    $http({
        url: user.update_path, 
        method: "POST",
        data: {user_id: user.id, draft: true}
    });
};
```

But whenever this function is called, I am getting **`ReferenceError: $http is not defined`** in my console. Can someone help me understanding what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 377, accepted):

Probably you haven't injected `$http` service to your controller. There are several ways of doing that.

Please read [this reference about DI](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). Then it gets very simple:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
   // ... your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why Angular's own documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) has this error.

Answer (score 83):

I have gone through the same problem when I was using

```
    myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope,) {
        //$http was not working in this
    }]);
```

I have changed the above code to given below. Remember to include $http(2 times) as given below.

```
 myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
      //$http is working in this
 }]);
```

and It has worked well.

Answer (score 4):

Just to complete [Amit Garg answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22125671/4927984), there are several ways to inject dependencies in AngularJS.

---

You can also use [`$inject`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to add a dependency:

```
var MyController = function($scope, $http) {
  // ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
```