# Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm having a bit of trouble using $http using the AngularJS framework. I've read several of the other posts about this error but I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The error is 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined' and the code is:

```
function removePupil(val) {  
  var string = 'Jon:jon@aaa.com:George:george@aaa.co.uk:Matthew:matthew@aaa.com:';
  var pupilNowRemoved = string.replace(val, '');
  var data = {
     "customer[id]":  {{ customer.id }},
     "metafield[customer.pupils]": pupilNowRemoved,
  };      
  $http.post('/a/custmeta', $.param(data),
     {"headers" : {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     console.log('Removed pupil')
  }). error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     console.log('Did not remove pupil')
  });
}
```

Comment: have you injected `$http` in your controller function as dependency?

Comment: @Pankaj No I hadn't should it have this after the first line: `app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){` and on the second to last line `)]};` ? Thanks for your help, Matt

Comment: yes, you are correct, you can refer to below answer as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs ReferenceError: $http is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759120/angularjs-referenceerror-http-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include $http in your controller like this:

```
.controller('MyController', ['$http', function ($http) {}];
```